# How to Disable Drawer Navigation (page)Click in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation for drawer navigation in my React Native app. I have a `Drawer.Screen` component where I'm trying to disable clicks on the navigation item based on a certain condition.
Here's my code:

```
<Drawer.Screen
   name="ProductPriceListPDF"
   component={ProductPricelistPDF}
   options={{
      // drawerLockMode: authorizedEntriesCount > 0 ? 'unlocked' : 'locked-closed',
      headerShown: false,
      drawerLabel: '- Product Price list PDF',
      drawerLabelStyle: {
          color: authorizedEntriesCount > 0 ? '#2D2D2D' : '#808080',
      },
      //  drawerActiveTintColor:"#ffff",
      // disableDrawerClick: true,
   }}
/>
```

Comment: You can specify onClick handler on your component and add necessary conditions for drawer navigation.